# Display single row of object data in a datagridview after selecting an item from combo box

Tags: c#

I have a class `Person` with data members `fullName`, `adress`, `occupation`.

I made a `List` of the type `Person` and stored inside of it a couple of objects of type `Person`.

There's a combo box, and a datagridview on my Windows Forms GUI.

What I wanted to do is when you select an item from the combo box(it gets populated automatically with `Persons` objects from the `List`) datagridview displays a single row, showing the currently selected item's `fullName` and `address`.

For getting the information about a person from the list I use a method I created - `PersonInfo(string id)`. This method returns the `Person` object. Then I use that object like so:

```
private void combobox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
Person myObj = PersonInfo(combobox.SelectedText.ToString());
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
row.Cells["cFullName"].Value = myObj.fullName;
row.Cells["cAddress"].Value = myObj.address;
}
```

Problem is I get a null exception which is usually located at the line `row.Cells["cFullName"].Value = myObj.fullName;`. I think `combobox.SelectedText.ToString()` is what causing this but don't know which other method to use to grab info from combo box and pass it to the `PersonInfo`.

Comment: This code is located where?? maybe you are passing an empty string to personinfo?

Comment: The code is located inside `combobox_SelectedValueChanged` event. I updated the snippet to show it.

Comment: How do you populate ComboBox items? You should populate it with objects, set ComboBox.DisplayMember to property you wish to see displayed and use SelectedItem to retrieve Person object directly.

Comment: So is probably running when you first fill the combo.. can you debug and tell us when the error occurs ?? (first choice, second choice, startup)..

Comment: It is just a static list. Since I have only 2 persons I refer to them inside the combo box with their respective indexes - 1 and 2.

Comment: @gbinchi Combo fills fine. It is just as soon as I select an item(any item) it gives me null exception. I believe the PersonInfo doesn't receive correct argument, or doesn't receive it at all since that's how I plan to display the related into in the datagridview later on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it relies on SelectedText which is empty at this particular moment. What you should do is to use DataBinding by assigning list of Persons to ComboBox and work with objects, thus eliminating the need to locate matching entry. Persons need to have public properties __ fullname __ and __ address __ otherwise binding will not work.

In form OnLoad assign DataSource:

```
combobox.DataSource = myListOfPersons;
// this can be set in designer but for brevity I set it here
combobox.DisplayMember = "fullname"; // Case must match.
```

Your handler now finds selected Person by simply casting SelectedItem.

```
private void combobox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person myObj = (Person)combobox.SelectedItem;
    // filling the grid
    dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<Person> { myObj };
}
```

As a side note, but flaring one, the use of debugging tools will make life much easier. Press F9 on line where you want execution to pause, run application and when it stops hover you mouse over variable/member names to see their values, or right click and press  QuickWatch to see values of all the properties of an object. This tools only would tell you that myObj is null, and further inspection of SelectedText would tell you that it is empty, disabling PersonInfo function to find suitable Person.